Flutter App wont open on Phone after Release
I've been developing android apps for years and uploading them successfully. Now I wanted to try flutter, but it doesn't work as I thought. I developed the app, then built a release appbundle, uploaded it to test in-app purchases (i.e. closed alpha) and now i wanted to change a few things again, but the app just wont start anymore.
It works with the emulator, but when I connect the phone and start it, the display goes black and nothing happens. So the app won't load.
I've already tried flutter clean, run flutter (terminal), etc.
With run flutter the app starts, but somehow in a completely different version (I use version control, so github) and I really don't know what to do anymore. I don't want to work with the emulator, because my laptop is not the fastest and it takes forever.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.

This is the message that is displayed and it gets stuck there. When I uninstall the app, it installs and then gets stuck there.
Does this have anything to do with the release version? I've already updated the version, but it didn't help. Before the release everything worked great.
Btw, I'm using Android Studio
I ran flutter clean, because I read it somewhere else, but didn't worked.
I Updated the version.

The flutter doctor command says: no issues found!. Is the released version the problem here?

When I build a apk and put it into the phone, install it than I can start it with the phone, but otherwise not. so debuggin isnt possible at this point. Please help me

mind giving more info regarding this version problem. You installed the app from playstore and then try to build app in real device with debug mode right? or am i missing something?

Please provide more info e.g.

What phone you are using to install the apk
Which packages you are using in the pubspect.yaml file
Your manifest file

Are you trying to load any data when the application is loading (e.g. fetching some data from API on the splash screen)
